# The findminimum gives a saddle point

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to use FindMaximum to find a local minimum of a simple function.But sometimes it gives me a saddle point.
For example,

```
Clear["Global`*"]
V = -23500 v11^2 + v11^4/2 - 31250 v21^2 + 2 v11^2 v21^2 + v21^4/2 - 
v11^2 v21 v31 - v11 v21^2 v31 - 39000 v31^2 + 2 v11^2 v31^2 - 
v11 v21 v31^2 + 2 v21^2 v31^2 + v31^4/2;
grad = Grad[V, {v11, v21, v31}];
hessian = Grad[grad, {v11, v21, v31}];
m1 = FindMinimum[V, {{v11, 154}, {v21, 0}, {v31, 0}}]
Eigenvalues[hessian /. m1[[2]]]
```

yields

```
{-2.76125*10^8, {v11 -> 153.297, v21 -> 0., v31 -> 0.}}
{94000., 48494.9, -994.949}
```

i tried changing the precision，but it didn't work.Sometimes changing the method to PrincipalAxis will give correct results, but not always.
Can someone explain the reason?

Comment: Try `FindMinimum[V, {{v11, 154}, {v21, 0.1}, {v31, 0.1}}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 16]`.

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

V = -23500 v11^2 + v11^4/2 - 31250 v21^2 + 2 v11^2 v21^2 + v21^4/2 - 
   v11^2 v21 v31 - v11 v21^2 v31 - 39000 v31^2 + 2 v11^2 v31^2 - 
   v11 v21 v31^2 + 2 v21^2 v31^2 + v31^4/2;
grad = Grad[V, {v11, v21, v31}];
hessian = Grad[grad, {v11, v21, v31}];
```

[`FindMinimum`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMinimum.html) only searches for a **local minimum**

```
m1 = FindMinimum[V, {{v11, 154}, {v21, 0}, {v31, 0}}]

(* {-2.76125*10^8, {v11 -> 153.297, v21 -> 0., v31 -> 0.}} *)

Eigenvalues[hessian /. m1[[2]]]

(* {94000., 48494.9, -994.949} *)
```

[`Minimize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minimize.html) will find a global minimum (but may not necessarily be unique)

```
m1 = Minimize[V, {v11, v21, v31}, Reals]

(* {-760500000, {v11 -> 0, v21 -> 0, v31 -> -10 Sqrt[390]}} *)

Eigenvalues[hessian /. m1[[2]]] // N

(* {156000., 141013., 61487.4} *)
```

If the variables are constrained to be nonnegative then

```
m1 = Minimize[{V, v11 >= 0, v21 >= 0, v31 >= 0}, {v11, v21, v31}, Reals]

(* {-760500000, {v11 -> 0, v21 -> 0, v31 -> 10 Sqrt[390]}} *)

Eigenvalues[hessian /. m1[[2]]] // N

(* {156000., 141013., 61487.4} *)
```